# Linq2Xml Parse Output from REST web service

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-xml

I am attempting to parse the XML output from a REST web service and have been pointed in the direction of using Linq2Xml to query the XML for the attributes that I am after.  The XML output is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"standalone="yes" ?>
<Response Status="OK">
  <Item Name="NumberZones">2</Item>
  <Item Name="CurrentZoneID">10001</Item>
  <Item Name="CurrentZoneIndex">1</Item>
  <Item Name="ZoneName0">Westralia</Item>
  <Item Name="ZoneID0">0</Item>
  <Item Name="ZoneGUID0">{81C56183-31DA-45C2-90C3-81609F01B38B}</Item>
  <Item Name="ZoneName1">Lounge</Item>
  <Item Name="ZoneID1">10001</Item>
  <Item Name="ZoneGUID1">{eac0109e-0090-a992-7fba-dc67fe29e6e7}</Item>
</Response>
```

I am wanting to return in a datatable the ZoneID, ZoneName, and ZoneGUID, I am wanting the function to return something like:

```
id    name       guid
0     westralia  {81C56183-31DA-45C2-90C3-81609F01B38B}
10001 lounge     {eac0109e-0090-a992-7fba-dc67fe29e6e7}
```

I have been working on the following function to query the XML, and have gotten as far as attempting to return results (not even at the point of trying to manipulate the data to get it into the format that I am wanting).

```
Private Function getServerResponse_Linq(ByVal queryString As Uri) As DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("data")
    With dt
        .Columns.Add("name")
        .Columns.Add("Value")
    End With
    Dim loaded As XDocument = XDocument.Load(queryString.ToString)
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim query = From c In loaded.<Response> Select c
    For Each result In query
        dr = dt.NewRow
        With dr
            .Item("name") = result.@name
            .Item("value") = result.Value
        End With
    Next
    Return dt
End Function
```

The returned datatable is empty, I have confirmed that result does have the XML assigned, and result.value is the string version of the XML file (200Westralia0{81C56183-31DA-45C2-90C3-81609F01B38B}Lounge10001{eac0109e-0090-a992-7fba-dc67fe29e6e7})

Is anyone able to provide assistance in how I can read from the REST XML example above the name (ZoneName%) and the attribute value (Westralia and Lounge)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems I can see with your code snippet. First, instead of

```
    Dim query = From c In loaded.<Response> Select c
```

you need

```
    Dim query = From c In loaded.<Response>.Elements Select c
```

or even just

```
    Dim query = loaded.<Response>.Elements
```

to fetch the Items rather than the Response.

Also, you need to add

```
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
```

to your loop, otherwise your new row won't get added to the DataTable.

Finally, XML is case sensitive so you need to use `@Name`, not `@name`.

Comment: Great! it is always the simple things (well if you know them that is).  These changes worked perfectly, if only I could claim back the last 3 hours.